# Binding socket before setsockopt

Tags: sockets, ip

Is there any undefined behavior if you bind a socket before all setsockopts are set?
For a multicast socket, does it change the outcome?

Comment: When you run the program, given your variants, what is the result?

Answer (score 1):

There is no undefined behaviour, but setting say the SO_REUSEADDR option after binding can't have any possible effect, so it's pointless.